# How can I avoid auto-linking of URLs?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Embedded URLs are automatically linked by default, like e.g. http://localhost/.

Is there a way to avoid this auto-linking besides enclosing them in backticks (formatting them as code), like `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Can you describe a situation where code formatting is not appropriate, and the URL shouldn't auto-link?

Comment: `http://localhost` is already a good example where you don't want to have auto-links, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39997673/432681 as concrete example.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: Code blocks are perfectly valid, there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is. Replace one of the characters in the url with an html entity:

http://www.google.com
Raw: `http:/&#47;www.google&#46;com`

As you can see, I replaced one of the slashes with `&#47;`, and the last period with `&#46;`, which breaks the url, as far as markdown is concerned.

Apparently the edit *preview* still renders the url, but the actual post doesn't.

Comment: Good point! I didn't think of that. But this rather looks like a workaround for a missing escape feature. I wonder if there's a "clean" solution for it.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: This _is_ the only way to escape HTML, though.

Comment: I just realized that this solution does not work for comments, unfortunately.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: I don't know of any option that works, in comments, other than code: `http://localhost/`

Comment: This answers my question, thank you! I just waited if somebody else has a better solution. Can this be seen as a feature request or do I have to post it somewhere else to be seen by the Stack Exchange developers?

Comment: @SebastianZartner: You can submit a FR, but you'll have to come up with a _very_ good reason you need unformatted urls in comments.

Comment: I'm asking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285778/allow-to-avoid-auto-linking.

Comment: this doesn't work on stackoverflow, at least in the preview.

Comment: @Boris: Hm, that's odd. The preview is inconsistent with the rendered output, apparently.

Comment: oh yea, if I click to Edit on your answer it links the url text in the preview

Comment: @Cerbrus I swear you could make a drinking game out of whenever SO breaks the editor in some or another way

Answer (score 3):

You can put a backslash before the colon:

http://localhost/

```
http\://localhost/
```

For some reason, the preview doesn't work properly with this (and you cannot use WYSIWYG  mode on the new Stacks editor, not even for a second — but then again not much works with that).

Because of these limitations, I prefer using code format.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Jeremy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119811) in an answer to [a similar question on the global Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119801), you can insert `<nolink>`.

For example, `http<nolink>://www.google.com` would render like this:

> http://www.google.com

Comment: This is risky to use. I used to use a similar trick and it was ruined when markdown parsing changed slightly. Your hack doesn't work in the new Stacks editor.